# How to allow requests to POST endpoint in a RestController in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on a Spring web project with Spring Security. I need now to add a RestController with an endpoint to use some of the project's functions from another project. I have configured the security and had no problem with any other public endpoint, but I can't access my new endpoint directly even if I have declared it in my security configuration, I'm just getting my login html as the response. I even have another RestController with a get request that works fine without login.

I have this securityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{
@Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http){
        try{
            http.authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/api/call", (...)).permitAll() //It should be available, all the other endpoints work
                    .anyRequest().authenticated());

            http.formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling();

            http.logout()
                    (...)

            return http.build();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the endpoint in my RestController:

```
@RestController
public class CallRestController {
    //Autowireds and references

    @PostMapping("/api/call")
    public ResponseEntity<CallRequest> call(@RequestBody CallRequest callRequest){
        try{
            //(Do stuff with the data)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(callRequest, HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (Exception exception){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

It should process the data and then send a response (either 200 and the original body or 500).
The model that represents the body is (with lombok annotation):

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class CallRequest {
    public String fromRef;
    public String toRef;
}
```

The JSON body I'm sending is:

```
{
    "fromRef": "String",
    "toRef": "String"
}
```

Is there anything else I need to have in order to make this post endpoint available without authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be an issue due to CORS. Try adding the following config to your class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{
@Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http){
        
            httpcsrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()).authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/api/call").permitAll() 
                    .anyRequest().authenticated());

            http.formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling();

            http.logout()
                    (...)

            return http.build();
        
        
    }
}
```

For now, I have disable CORS but you can also ignore certain endpoints by using:

```
csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(<<ANY ENDPOINT URL>>)
```

Comment: This was helpful as I could get to the problem, but I think I didn't undestand your example. I made it work adding this at the beginning of my config class:
`http.cors().and().csrf().disable()`